# BNE branch in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

Right now I'm preparing for a test in computer architecture, and being stuck in a task that I don't really understand.
* $1=4, $2=2, $3=x
Here's the code

```
LOOP:
ADDI $2,$2-1
SLL $2,$2,2
MULT $3,$1
MFLO $3
SW $3, 0($2)
BNE $2,$1,LOOP
```

My question is, which value does $2 have after this? Is this 4 or 4x?

Comment: Excuse me, but where is the branch in that code? I don't see any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it will be clearer if you write it out as ordinary paper math:

```
$1  = 4
$2  = 2
$3  = x
LOOP:
$2  = $2 -1
$2  = $2 * 2^2
$lo = $3 * $1
$3  = $lo
"contents of memory address in $2" = $3 
if $2 != $1 GOTO LOOP
```

Comment: Yup, but I'm not sure what the 'sw' does. It will write the value of $3 in $2, right?

Comment: sw stores to a memory location, not a register. http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html

It's like a pointer dereference in C. `sw $3 0($2)` basically means *($2 + 0) = $3.

Comment: @VanGan: yup, `sw` means *store word*, where a MIPS machine word is 32 bits.

Comment: It's really weird to be writing to such a small memory address. Are you sure you've transcribed the assignment correctly?

Comment: @Crashworks: Yes It's in the task. We're given some lines of codes, and have to guess if the branch is taken or not

Comment: @VanGan  Well, you've worked that out. But here's something to consider: of those lines of code, which are actually relevant to answering the question?

Comment: ADDI $2,$2-1
SLL $2,$2,2

That makes $2=4=$1, BNe mean branch if not equal

Comment: Yup, I'm just a little confused with the store word line

Comment: @VanGan  Yeah, I'm confused by it too. It's so completely out of place that I wonder if the assignment is written correctly.